# Meaning of "What else have you up nights?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

This particular sentence I found someone speaking to a person worried about some problematic situations. I searched the web and got that nights = at night. And, up = A problem(could be).

So, Is she asking, "What were the other problems you faced at night?" OR the meaning is all different?

Note: The given question has been taken from 13 reasons why, ep. 4(at 18:18).

The scene goes like this:

> Hannah : I just couldn't sleep last night.
>
> Friend : Were you obsessed with history exam or something?
>
> Hannah: Oh, no!
>
> Friend : **What else have you up nights?**
>
> Hannah : I think someone was taking my pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual quote, according to [springfield springfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=13-reasons-why-2017&episode=s01e04) is:

> What else has you up nights?

This means the same as "what else keeps you awake at night?".  When someone has problems, they can make sleeping difficult (called insomnia). We talk about problems "keeping" or "having us up nights" or "at night". The actual problem might have nothing to do with the night, but it is in bed that we can't help thinking about them.

> My daughter's school fees have me up nights worrying about how I can afford them, so I'm always tired at work.